# Can I create other #define's with a preprocessor function?

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I know I will be punished after asking this, still I'd like to do something like this:

```
#define DEF_CLASS(x) \ 
  #define CLASS x \
  #define CONSTRUCTOR CLASS::CLASS \
  #define COPY_CONSTRUCTOR(x) CONSTRUCTOR(const CLASS& x)
```

That is I'd like to have a "#define" function which dynamically defines other "#defines".

I have an IDE which is not capable of refactoring, furthermore I'd like to make constructors, especially copy constructor to stand out due to its special role.
Therefore I aim to program my c++ class definitions like this:

```
CONSTRUCTOR(int i):i(i){}
COPY_CONSTRUCTOR(other):i(other.i){}
void CLASS::fun1()
{
  //...
}
```

For that, currently I need to copy&paste three #define lines. I would rather do those automatically. Is there any way to pull this off using the preprocessor?

Comment: This syntax looks more confusing. What's wrong with the way it is now?

Comment: If one has kilometers long class names or narrow screens, like me, the code is just soo much more readable, not to mention easier refactoring. I knew it would freak some people out, but I think it is closer how we think (although I admit, not very C++-y...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a `DEF_CLASS(x)` macro is not possible. Macros aren't stateful. The best you can do is:

```
#define CONSTRUCTOR CLASS::CLASS
#define COPY_CONSTRUCTOR(x) CONSTRUCTOR(const CLASS& x)

...

#define CLASS X
    CONSTRUCTOR(int i):i(i){}
    COPY_CONSTRUCTOR(other):i(other.i){}
    void CLASS::fun1()
    {
      //...
    }
#undef CLASS

#define CLASS Y
    CONSTRUCTOR(int i):i(i){}
    COPY_CONSTRUCTOR(other):i(other.i){}
    void CLASS::fun1()
    {
      //...
    }
#undef CLASS
```

But I **strongly** urge you not to abuse the preprocessor like this. Why obfuscate the normal C++ syntax with these macros? Accept C++ for what it is; don't try to make it into a different, friendlier language.

Comment: Thanks! Great workaround! I'd do this because it helps refactoring a lot, also makes the code more transparent.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs If I could make **strongly** even bolder, I would. This type of thing is exactly why Java designers decided not to have a preprocessor.

Comment: Well, you accidentally have an extra "\" in your code. It works without it. If you look under the hood, there are so many nasty #define tricks (just look at the definition of assert in XCode), that this one does not make things really worse. But, there are not many #define tricks I use, thanks for warning me off.

Answer (score 2):

No -- §16.3.4/3:

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one [...]